# Bootstrap Image Gallery не работает

Tags: javascript, css

Подскажите люди добрые, просидел вчера пол ночи, не смог понять что происходит. Пытаюсь использовать Bootstrap Image Gallery Делаю все по документации, все ведет себя нормально, никаких ошибок в консоли js, инспектор показывает все элементы, только они все невидимые!

Посмотрите пожалуйста страницу, может свежим взглядом увидите что-либо! 
[link text](http://id.nichost.ru/index.php/zhenskaya-odezhda/bryuki/2-uncategorised/9-rubashkazh1)

Comment: Пробовали делать так, как написано?
Include the following scripts at the *bottom of the body* of your webpage

Comment: Сделал, все равно не работает, не думаю что имеет значение сверху скрипты подключены или снизу, а поджключены они были.   


 <script src="/templates/beez5/javascript/jquery.blueimp-gallery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/templates/beez5/javascript/bootstrap-image-gallery.min.js"></script> 
  </body>